# PHP float/double stored as MySQL DECIMAL

Tags: php, mysql, casting, floating-point, decimal

i ran into a really strange problem with storing values in MySQL. The premise:

I have a table that uses `DECIMAL(15,8)` to store monetary values (like the total of order), but when i try to insert for example:

```
2,45545345
```

this is stored as

```
2.00000000
```

I tried MySQL's FORMAT/CAST functions but still the same output.

This is how the query gets generated:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO `random_table_name` SET currency_value = '" . floatval($value) . "'");
```

i also tried `doubleval`, but same result. The funny thing is though that this same piece of code was working fine a couple of weeks ago and i can't recall any changes to the db structure or the db class that can cause this.

Comment: Does your script use `setlocale`?

Comment: Yes, but i can't turn it off or remove it.

Comment: What locale is it? `floatval` will convert `"2,45545345"` to `2.0` or `2.45545345` depending on locale.

Comment: It should work in multi-language environment, so that's why i'm looking for a bit more generic approach. The current issue though is with ro_RO

Edit::
Setting the locale to en_US does the trick, but is there another (cleaner) way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to replace the `,` with `.`

Like this:

```
number_format($value, 8, '.') // 8 = number of decimals, . = decimal separator
```

However, your problem seems to be related to the current locale. You need to look into the following: [setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) and [localeconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php)

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US'); // NOT TESTED, read up on the appropriate syntax
```

This is the appropriate way of doing this, the alternative would be (as suggested below), to do a `str_replace(',', '.')`, but you have to do the reverse every time you want to output strings.

There is another option though, you can set the MySQL locale to `en_US`.

Comment: Not a solution as it produces the same result - 2.0000000000

Comment: Indeed. You need to set the appropriate locale first. US locale should do the trick, not sure about the syntax, so I added the links so you can look it up.

Comment: Thank you Vlad, setlocale as suggest by Salman is the culprit here!

Answer (score 3):

Replace the `,` with `.` before inserting into db:

```
$value = str_replace( ',', '.', $value);
```

This will create a valid number, that can be safely inserted into the database. Or just add it just inside your query:

```
INSERT INTO `random_table_name` SET currency_value = '" . str_replace( ',', '.', $value ) . "'
```

Comment: One of the first things i tried - doesn't work, the value gets rounded to 2 by the DB

Comment: `str_replace` can't round your number to 2

Comment: str_replace does not, but the DB stores the value as 2.000000 even when using MySQL's CAST/FORMAT functions